# How to iterate by all not empty rows without using break or continue statement?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I want to get data from Excel file. I'm using `while` loop, iterator and `hasNext()` method to go by all rows.
My problem: sometimes after rows with data there are empty rows (propably with cell type string and value "" or `null`), which I don't want to iterate by. 
So I added method `isCellEmpty()`:

```
public static boolean isCellEmpty(final Cell cell) {
    if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        return true;
    }
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and added it after starring while loop in main method:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    row = rowIterator.next();
    if (isCellEmpty(row.getCell(2))) {
        break;
    }
    // some code ...
}
```

But now I have a break statement. How can I iterate by all not empty rows without using break or continue? Now (with break) my algorithm is working properly - I'm getting data which I need. I'm just wondering if it's possible to write code without `break` or `continue`.

Comment: Do you mean `continue;` ?

Comment: while `break` will terminate the loop, `continue` will start the next iteration if that's what you're looking for

Comment: No, whit break my algorithm is working properly - I'm getting data which I need. I'm just wondering if it's possible to write code without break or continue.
I edited question to clarify that.

Comment: Why not to keep the `break`? It's far more readable than the suggested solutions? If you're just interested in other solutions from learning perspective, its a different story then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep your `while` loop, and avoid a break, the easiest is probably a status boolean, eg

```
boolean inData = true;
while (rowIterator.hasNext() && inData) {
   row = rowIterator.next();
   if (row == null || isCellEmpty(row.getCell(2))) {
      inData = false;
   } else {
      // Use the row
   }
}
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest [reading the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), there are other approaches you could take which might work even better!

Oh, and don't forget that rows can be `null`, so you need to check that before you try fetching the cell

Comment: Suppose In your sheet data is filled from row 1 to 50 but in between there is a row number 30 which is blank then this will not Iterate after row number 30.

Comment: This is a baloney answer ^^^ `next()` throws an exception if the row is empty/without data.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like POI have no enanchements or features to iterate just over non-empty rows.

POIS' devs posted about this subject. Check out [Apache POI HSSF+XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) sections **Iterate over rows and cells** and **Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells**

Note that POI works with *Iterators*, so instead of *loops*, I would use [Apache IteratorUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils.html) from *Apache Commons Collections*, which is likely to be alredy in your classpath due to some transitive dependency.

In order to make your code cleaner and readable, the solution would be similiar to

```java
    import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;

    public class ValidRowPredicate implements Predicate{
        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
           Row row = (Row) object;
           Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
           if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
              return false;
           } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && 
                      cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
             return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
    }
```

The consumer would looks like

```java
    Iterator<Row> rawIterator = rowIterator;
    Iterator<Row> cleanIterator = IteratorUtils.filteredIterator(rawIterator , new ValidRowPredicate());

    while(cleanIterator.hasNext()){
       Row row = cleanIterator.next();
       // some code
    }
```

You might belive that we are iterating *book* 2 times but we aren't.

The first loop does, but further iterations are over a subset of *valid* rows. Additionaly, we made *reusable* the validation of *empty cell #2*.
We also got a reliable *Iterator* which only have valid and computable entries.

*Predicates* gives lot of possibilites. Like chaining Predicats by inheritance or composition.

Its cost is in infact, the first loop all over the main Iterator. But the result worth it.

*IteratorUtils* as *CollectionUtils* are really good *utils* that we often have'm in the classpath but we ignore.

Comment: I think your solution seems more clean and appropriate among the rest but only if he needs such additional features.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get the question right, are you looking for something like this?

```
Row row;
while (rowIterator.hasNext() 
          && !isCellEmpty((row = rowIterator.next()).getCell(2))) {
    // do something with row
}
```

This would process all rows until it finds an empty cell and ends the loop.

Comment: this is more elegent

Comment: Throws `NullPointerException` if there are `null` rows in the collection. Well, maybe its just me but it makes code a bit less readable to my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to exit a loop without using `break`:

- Use some other control flow, e.g. `return`, `throw`;
- Add an extra condition to the loop guard:

  ```
  boolean shouldContinue = true;
  while (shouldContinue && rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    row = rowIterator.next();
    if (isCellEmpty(...)) {
      shouldContinue = false;
    }
  }
  ```
- Exhaust the iterator inside the loop body:

  ```
  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    row = rowIterator.next();
    if (isCellEmpty(...)) {
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) rowIterator.next();
    }
  }
  ```

Or just use `break`. It's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Change your function `isCellEmpty()` use `switch` than a `nested if-else`.

```
public static boolean isCellEmpty(final Cell cell) {
   switch(cell.getCellType()){
       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK :
       case cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :
          if(StringUtils.isBlank(cell.getCellValue())
               return true;
          else
               return false;
         break;
       default :
               return false;
     break;               
   }
```

}

Now use this code

```
boolean hasCellData= true;
while (rowIterator.hasNext() && hasCellData) {
   row = rowIterator.next();  //iterate through each rows.
   if (row == null || isCellEmpty(row.getCell(2))) {
      hasData = false;
   } else {
      //if row contains data then do your stuffs.
   }
}
```

This `while (rowIterator.hasNext() && hasCellData)` loop will stop at point of time if a row contains `null` values. It never check whether beyond of this row have some data.

> **Example** :- Suppose In your sheet  data is filled from row 1 to 50 but in between there is a row number 30 which is blank then this will not Iterate after row number 30.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be too simplistic but wouldn't the following be enough?

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    row = rowIterator.next();
    if (!isCellEmpty(row.getCell(2))) {
        // some code ...
    }
}
```

If we would like to stop the iteration once an empty row/cell is encountered the following approach could be taken:

```
for(boolean shouldContinue = true; shouldContinue && rowIterator.hasNext(); ) {
   if (!isCellEmpty(row.getCell(2))) {
        // some code ...
    } else {
        shouldContinue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP says `break` and not `continue` :)

Comment: Not fully getting your feedback. Within the ticket the following is stated: _How can I iterate by all not empty rows without using break or continue? Now (with break) my algorithm is working properly_. So I thought, lets remove the `break` statement :)

Comment: This solution doesn't *break* the loop.. rather it *continues* to iterate it even after when an empty cell is found unlike the code OP has posted. So functionally both are not equivalent.

Comment: Extended the answer so that functional wise the existing and proposed solution are similar (i hope).

Answer (score 0):

Able to remove empty rows based on the Laiv's answer's. I've modified to support passing the Row. This is the modified answer

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ValidRowPredicate implements Predicate<Row> {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Row row) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
            return false;
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING &&
                cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Credits goes to Laiv