# Why "cellIterator.hasNext()" is getting "TRUE" even though cell has empty value

Tags: java, xssf, hssf

consider below screenshot of my excelSheet

[image]

Now consider below code, which will iterate every row then iterate every cell and then print cell value.

```
public void excelData2(int sheetNo) {
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNo).rowIterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Actually by looking at excel sheet we can see there are 2 rows and 1 column right!!.

So, the first `while` loop is iterating two times as expected :) , but inner `while` loop which is `cellIterator` is looping 26 times instead of 1 time even though next cell's has no value in it. Ideally when in 2nd iteration `cellIterator.hasNext()` should give false right? why it is giving true value till 26 times? anyone have idea?

**Note:** I don't want to put condition like `isEmpty()` or `==""` etc.

**Note2:** I have another solution in my mind i can go with that. But i want to know why this is happening.

Comment: I haven't worked with an `Iterator<Cell>` but it seems to me that `hasNext` would return true if another cell exists because an empty cell is still a cell.

Comment: Ohh.. But is there anyway to get only count of columns having data in it instead of putting conditions like `isEmpty()` or `==""` etc

Comment: Why you wouldn't want to use the tool provided by the API to examine the contents of the cell.

Comment: Yeah, i mean in my excel sheet in between there will be empty values, hence i don't wish to end up like this `cell` is the end, hence this many **no of columns** what we have.

Comment: My desire is to find how many columns we have in excel.

Comment: It looks like the code you wrote prints all the cells in the sheet. If you want a column count, get a single row instead of iterating them all.

Comment: Even though for single `row` it has inbuilt class like `row.getLastCellNum();` which is returning 1024 columns. Of course it is returning last column count. Instead of that i want last column having the value in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192833/discussion-between-the-head-rush-and-jagadeesh).

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304092/how-to-iterate-by-all-not-empty-rows-without-using-break-or-continue-statement

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304092/how-to-iterate-by-all-not-empty-rows-without-using-break-or-continue-statement

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs of POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFRow.CellIterator.html) (used by LibreOffice):

org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow.CellIterator

> returns all cells including empty cells

Answer (score -1):

You can use this and can skip the blank once:

```
if (nextCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
```